# Get error ORA-01722: invalid number while test function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a little bit confuse in this problem and I have no idea what's wrong here.
I have function like this

```
FUNCTION GET_ARTICLES_ADDIOTION_WORK(p_ataID IN INT)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
  rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  /*getArticlesAdditionalWork*/
BEGIN
 OPEN rc FOR
       SELECT  
              aa.ID,
              aa.Name,
              aa.Quantity,
              aa.Unit,
              aa.Price,
              aa.Deduct,
              aa.Account,
              aa.Created
            FROM 
               ata_articles aa
            LEFT JOIN
               weekly_report wr
            ON
               aa.wrId = wr.id
            WHERE 
               aa.AtaId = p_ataID
            AND 
               aa.type = 1
            AND
                (aa.wrId = 0 OR (wr.status = 2 OR wr.status = 5))
            ORDER BY Name;          
RETURN rc;
END GET_ARTICLES_ADDIOTION_WORK;
```

Somehow, when I  want to test does this function work fine I following statment

```
SELECT ATA_PACKAGE.GET_ARTICLES_ADDIOTION_WORK(2014) from dual
```

I get error

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

While I also try to run  query without function also same error occure.

```
SELECT  
  aa.ID,
  aa.Name,
  aa.Quantity,
  aa.Unit,
  aa.Price,
  aa.Deduct,
  aa.Account,
  aa.Created
FROM 
   ata_articles aa
LEFT JOIN
   weekly_report wr
ON
   aa.wrId = wr.id
WHERE 
   aa.AtaId = 2116
AND 
   aa.type = 1
AND
    (aa.wrId = 0 OR (wr.status = 2 OR wr.status = 5))
ORDER BY Name;
```

So far I check in table and ataId is NUMBER, it's not string. I have no idea what is wrong here ?
What couse this problem ? What I miss ? Where the error comes from ?

**Ata_Article Table Definition**

```
ACCOUNT VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ARTICLEPAYMENTTYPE  NUMBER(10,0)
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
CLIENTCOMMENT   VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENTEMAIL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
CLIENTFINALSTATUS   NUMBER(10,0)
CLIENTSTATUS    NUMBER(10,0)
CREATED DATE
DEDUCT  NUMBER(10,0)
EXTERNAL    NUMBER(10,0)
ID  NUMBER(10,0)
NAME    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PRICE   FLOAT
PROJECTID   NUMBER(10,0)
QUANTITY    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
SUPPLIERINVOICEID   NUMBER(10,0)
TABLETYPE   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
TOTAL   FLOAT
TYPE    VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
UNIT    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
WRID    NUMBER(10,0)
```

**Weekly_Report Table Definition**

```
ANSWERDATE  DATE
ANSWEREMAIL VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
ANSWERIP    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
ATAID   NUMBER(10,0)
COMMENT_    VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR)
CREATED DATE
DUEDATE DATE
EXTERNAL    NUMBER(10,0)
FINANCEID   NUMBER(10,0)
ID  NUMBER(10,0)
NAME    VARCHAR2(45 CHAR)
PARENT  NUMBER(10,0)
PDF_URL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
PROJECTID   NUMBER(10,0)
SEEN    DATE
STATUS  NUMBER(10,0)
TOKEN   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
WEEK    NUMBER(10,0)
YEAR    NUMBER(10,0)
```

Comment: Check the definition for column aa.AtaId. Is it varchar2? Such problems occurs while compairing number to a varchar2 column which has non-digit values.

Comment: No, It's now. I have alredy check. It is number

Comment: I would then check definition for all columns listed in join and in where clauses. Just try to comment "WHERE" clause for the beginning and let's see what will happen

I didn't see the table definition you've attached. Can you add definition for another table as well?

Comment: I add table definition for one table and I will add for second as well.

Comment: @ekochergin I add table definition for both table. You can check right now.

Comment: aa.type is varchar2 and is being compared to 1. This is the what I looked for.

Make it aa.type = '1' and give it a try. Let's see what will happen

Comment: no probs. When you see that problem again just check all the columns that are in joins/where clause. It helps in most cases.

Now I'll post an answer since it helped. Mark it as an answer please

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Sure, I have alredy mark as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a sort discussion we figurated out that the column aa.type has been defined as varchar2 and is being compared to a number. That was the root cause